# Perform selector or animation after view transition animation is finished

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm looking for a way to perform an animation *after* the transition to a view is finished, but *not* using `viewDidAppear:` because I only want the animation to occur when a notification is posted by the previous view.

I know about `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration: delay: options: animations: completion:` method, so I can set the delay to be the same as the view transition animation duration (that's a lot of words ending in -tion...), but would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean use a notification to enable a `BOOL` and only call the animation in `viewDidAppear:` if the `BOOL` is `YES`?

Comment: Thank you.  I thought of this but wondered if there might be a simpler way.  But now that you mention it, other approaches would probably be more complicated.  Submit your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidAppear` is probably the best place to start the animation. This way you don't have to worry about timing a delay because load times will vary between devices. To solve this problem you could simply place a `BOOL` condition in `viewDidAppear` and set it up so that the animation only starts if `BOOL == YES`.